# SageMakerTrainingOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, amazon-web-services

I have made an operator (surrounded by others operators) for training a model in sagemaker in airflow and I have doubts how would it be more readable or more pythonic. First I did this:

```
transform_data = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'transform_data',
        bash_command = 'blabla')

container = get_image_uri(boto3.Session().region_name,
                      'xgboost', repo_version='0.90-1')
estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
        container, 
        role = 'AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-201903XXX',
        train_instance_count = 1,
        train_instance_type = 'ml.m4.2xlarge',
        output_path = f"s3://production/models/{domain}-{product}-{today}",
        train_use_spot_instances = True,
        hyperparameters = {'num_round':'400',
                           'objective':'binary:logistic',
                           'eval_metric':'error@0.1',
                           'gamma':'5',
                           'scale_pos_weight':'10'}                              
        )

s3_input_train = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://production/data/{domain}-{product}-{today}/train_data.csv',
                                    content_type='text/csv')
s3_input_validation = sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://production/data/{domain}-{product}-{today}/validation_data.csv',
                                    content_type='text/csv')

job_name_timestamp = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

train_config = training_config(estimator=estimator,
                               inputs = {'train':s3_input_train,
                                         'validation':s3_input_validation},
                                         job_name = f'{domain}-{product}-{job_name_timestamp}')

model_training = SageMakerTrainingOperator(
            task_id = 'model_training',
            config = train_config,
            wait_for_completion = True)

model_deployment = OperatorX(blabla)
```

But then, I have gathered all the information about the training operator, motivated by not stopping the succession of operators in the code. So I have coded:

```
transform_data = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'transform_data',
        bash_command = 'blabla')

model_training = SageMakerTrainingOperator(
        task_id = 'model_training',
        config = training_config(
                estimator=sagemaker.estimator.Estimator
                (
                    container=get_image_uri(boto3.Session().region_name,
                                  'xgboost', repo_version='0.90-1'), 
                    role = 'AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20190XXXX',
                    train_instance_count = 1,
                    train_instance_type = 'ml.m4.2xlarge',
                    output_path = f"s3://production/models/{domain}-{product}-{today}",
                    train_use_spot_instances = True,
                    hyperparameters = {'num_round':'400',
                                       'objective':'binary:logistic',
                                       'eval_metric':'error@0.1',
                                       'gamma':'5',
                                       'scale_pos_weight':'10'}                              
                ),
               inputs = 
               {
                   'train':sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://production/data/{domain}-{product}-{today}/train_data.csv',
                                              content_type='text/csv'),
                   'validation':sagemaker.s3_input(s3_data='s3://production/data/{domain}-{product}-{today}/validation_data.csv',
                                                   content_type='text/csv')
               },
               job_name = f"{domain}-{product}-{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')}"),
        wait_for_completion = True)

model_deployment = OperatorX(blabla)
```

What do you think? Which is the best way? Doesn't it matter at all and both can be considered as good (or bad) code? thanks for your answers